# Querying all available devices using WebUSB's getDevices w/o prompt message?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webusb

Just discovered the new `WebUSB` API which allows the application to get an access to a specific device that plugged to the user's machine.

As part of my development I want to map the user's devices (for example, show a list of attached devices by querying their VendorID and ProductID).

I have noticed that in order to query all the user's available devices I have to use following code: `navigator.usb.requestDevice({filters:[]})`.

This code prompts a permission message to the user, which have to enable a specific device for the session.

My question - is it possible to query the Vendor IDs and Product IDs without permission? (of course without any attempt to use the actual device, just query it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. To get access to a device, you have to use `requestDevice`. This is one of the central security aspects of the API. From [the spec](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/#abusing-a-device):

> ...This API...requires a similarly generic mechanism for preventing a malicious page from abusing a device.
>
> The first of these protections is the `requestDevice()` function. The UA may display a permission prompt when this function is called. Even for a non-malicious page this action also preserves user privacy by preventing a site from connecting to a device before the user is aware that such a connection is possible.

Even the fact that the user *has* a given device is sensitive information your page/app should not be able to access without the user's permission.

Comment: Are there any other APIs which accessible to the vid and pid, which don't require the user's permission just to query them?

Comment: @GMe - I'm not aware of any, and again, just the fact of the user having a device attached is **sensitive information**. If the API made it possible to discover devices without notification, it wouldn't survive peer review in the standardization process.

Comment: Yeah.. That what I guessed. Thanks